# Как выбрать все html-элементы, имеющие namespace?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

Следующий код

```js
function go() {
  console.log(document.querySelectorAll("*|*"));
}
```

```html
<div>Some div</div>
<a:div>Smth from a</a:div>
<b:any>Smth from b</b:any>
<p>Just a p</p>
<button onclick="go()">Find</button>
```

находит все элементы на странице:

```
0: html
1: head
2: style
3: body
4: div
5: a:div
6: b:any
7: p
8: button
9: script
length: 10
```

А как найти только те, у которых задан нестандартный namespace?

```
0: a:div
1: b:any
length: 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Могу на JQuery элементы с заранее известными нэймспейсами нати.

```js
function go() {
  $('.result').append($('a\\:div'));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Some div</div>
<a:div>Smth from a</a:div>
<b:any>Smth from b</b:any>
<p>Just a p</p>
<button onclick="go()">Find</button>
<div class="result"></div>
```

Можно и без JQuery:

```
function go() {

    var elements = document.getElementsByTagNameNS('*','*');

    found = [];

    [].forEach.call(elements, function(element) {
        if (element.nodeName.indexOf(':') > 0) {
            found.push(element);
        }
    });

    found.forEach(function(element) {
        document.getElementById("result").appendChild(element);
    });
}
```

В сниппете код почему-то не работает, а при загрузке страницы из файла в Google Chrome — работает.

Почему вы не используете JQuery?

Comment: В каком браузере (современном) не будет работать, например?

Comment: Сейчас поискал: вроде, этот метод везде будет работать. А, всё же, почему без JQuery?

Comment: Работать должно везде, начиная с IE9.

Comment: Лично я принципиально не использую jQuery, потому что считаю абстракцию над абстракцией над абстракцией [для мобильных девайсов вставить ещё одно «над абстракцией» здесь] над абстракцией от железа в 99% случаев крайне избыточной, особенно учитывая, что и без него можно писать вполне приемлемый и рабочий код вроде приведённого в ответе. А почему автор не использует — не знаю

Comment: Без jQuery потому что мне это вообще для тестовых целей надо - хочу натравить что-нибудь на страницы с серверной разметкой, найти в ней определённые элементы и внутри них всё с неймспейсами. Элементы с неймспейсами относятся к серверной разметке и мне надо определить, что там может оказаться. Сначала хотел найти модуль html-парсера, потом решил особо не мучиться и натравить браузер далеком.

Comment: @andreymal, jQuery предоставляет весьма удобный интерфейс, так что в большинстве случаев отказываться от него смысла не вижу. Хотя было бы классно написать легковесный аналог, который просто делегирует соответствующую функциональность браузеру.

Comment: Интерфейс, безусловно, крут, но всё-таки хотелось бы это всё иметь в самом браузере, дабы лишних прослоек не возникало; к счастью, они к этому стремятся: появляются всякие там querySelector, и чем их больше добавляется, тем jQuery становится менее нужен. (Если зачем-то хочется разговор продолжить, то лучше удалиться в какой-нибудь чат, а то это всё не по теме)

Comment: @andreymal, методы-то они понемногу добавляют (хотя у IE опять проблемы), но вот чейнингом даже и не пахнет...

Comment: @andreymal jQuery нужен для написания более короткого (иногда ещё ради кроссбраузерности) кода. Не знаю про какие 3 абстракции речь, но, например, в C# вы бы тоже не стали использовать все библиотеки? Написали бы всё сами, как-то не создав при этом "абстракцию"? Пусть код будет длиннее, пусть в нём скорее всего больше ошибок, чем в отлаженной библиотеке, пусть на это уйдёт больше времени, зато без библиотек... Можно пойти дальше: посчитать C# ненужной абстракцией и начать писать всё на Ассемблере.

Comment: Почти так. Надо не гнушаться велосипедов, если их можно сделать за приемлемые сроки в прииемлемом качестве. Таскать за собой многомегабайтные тормозные библиотеки только ради того, чтобы вызывать там одну функцию - глупость.

Comment: @Qwertiy Мой ответ помог вам?

Comment: @VladimirSerykh, у меня мысль выбирать всё и фильтровать и так возникала, но думал, что должно быть возможно через один селектор типа `*|*:not(...)`. PS: плюс за ответ я поставил.

Answer (score 1):

Сделал так:

```js
function go() {
  console.log(Array.prototype.filter.call(document.querySelectorAll("*|*"), function(el) {
    return ~el.tagName.indexOf(":");
  }));
}
```

```html
<div>Some div</div>
<a:div>Smth from a</a:div>
<b:any>Smth from b</b:any>
<p>Just a p</p>
<button onclick="go()">Find</button>
```